# Как передать вывод из консоли в TextBox из другого класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть `NewClass.cs` в котором я собираю данные о `ipconfig` из `cmd`
Как мне из этого класса вывести данные ( через аргументы ) в `TextBox` который лежит на форме?!

```
public static class NewClass
{
     public static void Test()
     {
         ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo
         {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "ipconfig /all",
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
         };
         Process result = Process.Start(Info);
         result.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

На форме лежит `TextBox` нужно сделать вызов метода `Test(с передачей аргументов)` из класса`NewClass.cs` чтобы всё из командной строки `(cmd.exe)` выводилось в этот `TextBox` без появления консоли. 
Как это реализовать?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IProgress` колбэк здесь очень кстати.

```csharp
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s =>
    {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        textBox1.SelectedText = s + Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    });
    NewClass.Test(progress);
}
```

```csharp
public static class NewClass
{
    public static void Test(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K ipconfig /all";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
        process.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
        var handler = new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) => progress?.Report(e.Data));
        process.OutputDataReceived += handler;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += handler;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111823/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot-------textbox--).